# Converting base64 Image to file object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, image, file, blob

I am trying to create a file object from a base64 image which was cut from another image. I am able to do it but the resulting file size is almost thrice the actual size. Below is the function that I am using:

```
convertDataURItoFile(dataURI, fileName) {
    // convert base64 to raw binary data held in a string
    // doesn't handle URLEncoded DataURIs - see SO answer #6850276 for code that does this
    var byteString = atob(dataURI.split(',')[1]);

    // separate out the mime component
    var mimeString = dataURI.split(',')[0].split(':')[1].split(';')[0]

    // write the bytes of the string to an ArrayBuffer
    var ab = new ArrayBuffer(byteString.length);

    var ia = new Uint8Array(ab);
    for (var i = 0; i < byteString.length; i++) {
      ia[i] = byteString.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    // write the ArrayBuffer to a blob, and you're done
    var blob: any = new Blob([ia], { type: mimeString });

    //A Blob() is almost a File() - it's just missing the two properties below which we will add
    blob.lastModifiedDate = new Date();
    blob.name = fileName;
    //Cast to a File() type
    return <File>blob;
  }
```

Any idea on why the file size increasing so drastically? How can I compress it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: _"the resulting file size is almost thrice the actual size"_ How did you determine that the size of resulting `Blob` is a different size? If you want to set `.name` and `.lastModifiedDate` why do you not use `File` constructor? `File` inherits from `Blob`, `Blob` does not inherit from `File`.

Comment: Cannot reproduce resulting `Blob` which has `.size` greater than content of `data URI` passed. Though note, resulting `Blob` is not the same data content as passed `data URI`. Can you create a stacksnippets or plnkr https://plnkr.co to demonstrate  
_"the resulting file size is almost thrice the actual size"_? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mvce

Answer (score 3):

> I am trying to create a file object from a base64 image which was cut
>   from another image. I am able to do it but the resulting file size is
>   almost thrice the actual size.

Cannot reproduce resulting `.size` of `Blob` being thrice the size of the content of input `data URI`. Do you mean the `data URI` `.length` can be thrice the size of `Blob` `.size`?

```js
function convertDataURItoFile(dataURI, fileName) {
    // convert base64 to raw binary data held in a string
    // doesn't handle URLEncoded DataURIs - see SO answer #6850276 for code that does this
    var byteString = atob(dataURI.split(',')[1]);

    // separate out the mime component
    var mimeString = dataURI.split(',')[0].split(':')[1].split(';')[0]
    // write the bytes of the string to an ArrayBuffer
    var ab = new ArrayBuffer(byteString.length);

    var ia = new Uint8Array(ab);
    for (var i = 0; i < byteString.length; i++) {
      ia[i] = byteString.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    // write the ArrayBuffer to a blob, and you're done
    var blob = new Blob([ia], { type: mimeString });

    //A Blob() is almost a File() - it's just missing the two properties below which we will add
    blob.lastModifiedDate = new Date();
    blob.name = fileName;
    //Cast to a File() type
    console.log(`input data size: ${datauriLength} Blob.size: ${blob.size}`);
    return blob;
  }
  
const [datauri, filename] = ["data:image/png;base64,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", "filename.png"];

const datauriLength = datauri.length;

const reader = new FileReader;
reader.onload = () => {
  console.log(`data URI: ${reader.result}`)
  document.querySelector("iframe").src = reader.result;
};

reader.readAsDataURL(convertDataURItoFile(datauri, filename));
```

```html
<iframe></iframe>
```

If `.name` and `.lastModifiedDate` need to be added to `Blob`, you can substitute using `File` constructor for `Blob`, which expects file name parameter to be set at second parameter to `File` constructor, and optionally expected `.lastModidied` and or `.lastModifiedDate` parameters at third parameter to constructor.

```js
function convertDataURItoFile(dataURI, fileName) {
    // convert base64 to raw binary data held in a string
    // doesn't handle URLEncoded DataURIs - see SO answer #6850276 for code that does this
    var byteString = atob(dataURI.split(',')[1]);

    // separate out the mime component
    var mimeString = dataURI.split(',')[0].split(':')[1].split(';')[0]
    // write the bytes of the string to an ArrayBuffer
    var ab = new ArrayBuffer(byteString.length);

    var ia = new Uint8Array(ab);
    for (var i = 0; i < byteString.length; i++) {
      ia[i] = byteString.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    // write the ArrayBuffer to a blob, and you're done
    // use `File` constructor here
    var blob = new File([ia], fileName, { type: mimeString, lastModifiedDate: new Date() });

    //A Blob() is almost a File() - it's just missing the two properties below which we will add
    // blob.lastModifiedDate = new Date();
    // blob.name = fileName;
    //Cast to a File() type
    console.log(`input data size: ${datauriLength} Blob.size: ${blob.size}`);
    return blob;
  }
  
const [datauri, filename] = ["data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAASoAAADCCAYAAAD+Wo90AAAABHNCSVQICAgIfAhkiAAAApVJREFUeJzt1DEBACAMwLCBf88ggZMeiYJeXTPnDEDY/h0A8GJUQJ5RAXlGBeQZFZBnVECeUQF5RgXkGRWQZ1RAnlEBeUYF5BkVkGdUQJ5RAXlGBeQZFZBnVECeUQF5RgXkGRWQZ1RAnlEBeUYF5BkVkGdUQJ5RAXlGBeQZFZBnVECeUQF5RgXkGRWQZ1RAnlEBeUYF5BkVkGdUQJ5RAXlGBeQZFZBnVECeUQF5RgXkGRWQZ1RAnlEBeUYF5BkVkGdUQJ5RAXlGBeQZFZBnVECeUQF5RgXkGRWQZ1RAnlEBeUYF5BkVkGdUQJ5RAXlGBeQZFZBnVECeUQF5RgXkGRWQZ1RAnlEBeUYF5BkVkGdUQJ5RAXlGBeQZFZBnVECeUQF5RgXkGRWQZ1RAnlEBeUYF5BkVkGdUQJ5RAXlGBeQZFZBnVECeUQF5RgXkGRWQZ1RAnlEBeUYF5BkVkGdUQJ5RAXlGBeQZFZBnVECeUQF5RgXkGRWQZ1RAnlEBeUYF5BkVkGdUQJ5RAXlGBeQZFZBnVECeUQF5RgXkGRWQZ1RAnlEBeUYF5BkVkGdUQJ5RAXlGBeQZFZBnVECeUQF5RgXkGRWQZ1RAnlEBeUYF5BkVkGdUQJ5RAXlGBeQZFZBnVECeUQF5RgXkGRWQZ1RAnlEBeUYF5BkVkGdUQJ5RAXlGBeQZFZBnVECeUQF5RgXkGRWQZ1RAnlEBeUYF5BkVkGdUQJ5RAXlGBeQZFZBnVECeUQF5RgXkGRWQZ1RAnlEBeUYF5BkVkGdUQJ5RAXlGBeQZFZBnVECeUQF5RgXkGRWQZ1RAnlEBeUYF5BkVkGdUQJ5RAXlGBeQZFZBnVECeUQF5RgXkGRWQZ1RAnlEBeUYF5BkVkHcBRH8DgsmlTc8AAAAASUVORK5CYII=", "filename.png"];

const datauriLength = datauri.length;

const reader = new FileReader;
reader.onload = () => {
  console.log(`data URI: ${reader.result}`)
  document.querySelector("iframe").src = reader.result;
};

reader.readAsDataURL(convertDataURItoFile(datauri, filename));
```

```html
<iframe></iframe>
```

You can also utilize `fetch()` to create and get `Blob` representation of `data URI`, see Answer by @Endless at [Creating a Blob from a base64 string in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16245767/creating-a-blob-from-a-base64-string-in-javascript/36183085#)